# Merging two pandas data frames in python using outer merge not identifying identical values

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I am trying to merge two pandas data frames using a common column (I imported both data frames from csv files). The common column (key column) should have some identical values, but the majority are different, so I used an outer merge. I realized after performing the merge that my output was actually just data frame 2 added on to data frame 1, without the identical values from the key column actually merging into one row.

Example:

```
import pandas as pd

#read csv files as dataframes
df1 = pd.read_table("genelist1.csv", sep=",")
df2 = pd.read_table("genelist2.csv", sep=",")

#print first 4 rows df1
df1[:4]

gene_id      FC_1     p_1
name1        2     0.05
name2        3     0.01
name3        8     0.02

#print first 4 rows df2
df2[:4]

gene_id      FC_2     p_2
name1        8     0.03
name2        3     0.01
name4        8     0.02

#Use outer merge to merge the two data frames using gene_id as key
df_merged = pd.merge(df1, df2, how='outer', on=['gene_id'])
```

I want:

```
df_merged

gene_id      FC_1     p_1    FC_2    p_2
name1        2     0.05      8      0.03
name2        3     0.01      3      0.01
name3        8     0.02      nan    nan
name4        nan   nan       8      0.02
```

But I actually get:

```
df_merged

gene_id      FC_1     p_1     FC_2    p_2
name1        2     0.05      nan      nan
name2        3     0.01      nan      nan
name3        8     0.02      nan      nan
name1        nan    nan       8      0.03
name2        nan    nan       3      0.01
name4        nan    nan       8      0.02
```

To try and troubleshoot this, I used the following code which may actually point to what the issue is, but I determine what I'm doing wrong. For some reason I can't "find" the values in the data frame, even if I can see them there.

```
#print first 4 rows
df1[:4]

gene_id      FC_1     p_1
name1        2     0.05
name2        3     0.01
name3        8     0.02

'name1' in df1.gene_id

False

##The same is true when I do searches in df2, which might explain why the identical gene names aren't combining, but I have no idea why this is happening.
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, even if it is just pointing me towards a previously asked question I should have been looking at already.

Comment: I get your intended answer with your given example. I don't know why you are getting something different.

Comment: I second @chrisaycock. With your example data, the outer join renders your desired result. And you compare a single value to a series and so returns the False on a string comparison. Loop through series and check for `name1` in `df1.gene_id`

Comment: A general tip to see what's going on is instead of relying on just a printout to see what your dataframes look like, look at what `df1.info()` says.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to solve a similar problem. The first step was to use `df1.dtypes` and `df2.dtypes` to determine the data types of my columns. It turns out that my common columns, `A` and `B`, were of the `object` type in `df1`  and `int64` in the `df2`.

I ended up using `df1[['A','B']] = df1[['A','B']].astype('int64')` for both of those columns to ensure that `A` and `B` had the same data types in each data frame. The merge then worked correctly.